# Log input to serial port during boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, logs, serial-port

I have a LCD screen that is connected to the `/dev/ttyS0` serial port. During startup, the LCD screen displays gibberish without reason (nothing is written to it). This happens during the very early stages of startup and by the time the system is online I can't see what caused it.

My suspicion is that during startup a process writes to the `ttyS0` and immediately exists, since the LCD screen isn't cleared the text remains.

So the question is, is there anyway to log the inputs to the serial port during the boot process?